# How to get a level of isolation for div similar to one iframe provides?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So I have a project with `page.html` that has JS and CSS that can conflict with my `main.html`. I want to embed `page.html` contents into `main.html` without corrupting `main.html` logic. `iframe` currently does it for me yet I want to have elements from `main.html` sometimes hover over it and here is where I get to the problem with `iframe` approach. So I want to have isolated `div` is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to apply `all: initial` to your div and `all: unset` to its descendants.

```
#targetDiv {
  all: initial; /* blocking inheritance for all properties */
}
#targetDiv * {
  all: unset; /* allowing inheritance within #mydiv */
}
```

Comment: And what about JS objeccts?